# How to get real uptime?

Tags: uptime

Is there any easy way to calculate uptime excluding period system is suspended? I would like to count time I've spent in front of computer.

Comment: var/log/pm-suspend.log, will contain the last awake time ,using this ,uptime and current time you can manually find real uptime with subtraction.Guess this is not the easy way!!

Comment: @Stormvirux I can write script but it is the last resort

Comment: @Stormvirux I had the same idea, but wish I had found your suggestion first instead of figuring that out six years later!

Comment: The next time you sign on, let us know how you eventually ended up solving this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

On one hand this answer is six years late, on the other hand it's a blink of the eye if the internet is eternal!

You can get the real uptime with this little bash script:

```bash
$ suspendtime

Apr 07 05:53:34 to Apr 07 17:07:17 suspended 11 hours, 13 minutes, 43 seconds
Apr 07 21:56:34 to Apr 08 04:20:57 suspended 6 hours, 24 minutes, 23 seconds
      (... SNIP ...)
May 08 05:55:20 to May 08 16:32:37 suspended 10 hours, 37 minutes, 17 seconds
May 08 23:21:00 to May 09 07:02:05 suspended 7 hours, 41 minutes, 5 seconds

Linux uptime 2,813,939 seconds (4 weeks, 4 days, 13 hours, 38 minutes, 59 seconds)
64 Suspends 1,715,196 seconds (2 weeks, 5 days, 20 hours, 26 minutes, 36 seconds)
Real uptime 1,098,743 seconds (1 week, 5 days, 17 hours, 12 minutes, 23 seconds)
```

Linux will report uptime as 8 days and 40 minutes. The real uptime (after subtracting suspend time) is about 2 days and 18 hours.

---

### `suspendtime` bash script

Here's the code you can copy to your system:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: suspendtime
# PATH: $HOME/askubuntu/
# DESC: For: https://askubuntu.com/questions/321855/how-to-get-real-uptime
# DATE: November 6, 2019.

# NOTE: Calculate suspend time from systemd's journalctl

# UPDT: 2019-11-07 Fine-tune removing 0 Units in DaysMinutesStr
#       2020-05-09 Add "weeks" unit measure to DaysMinutes() function

# Duplicate DaysMinutes from ~/.bashrc for Ask Ubuntu
DaysMinutes () {

    local w d h m s
    (( w = ${1} / 604800 ))
    (( d = ${1}%604800 / 86400 ))
    (( h = (${1}%86400) / 3600 ))
    (( m = (${1}%3600) / 60 ))
    (( s = ${1}%60 ))
    DaysMinutesStr="$w weeks, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds"
    
    # Convert 1's to singular
    [[ ${DaysMinutesStr:0:2} = "1 " ]] && \
        DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/weeks/week}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 days/ 1 day}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 hours/ 1 hour}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 minutes/ 1 minute}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 seconds/ 1 second}"

    # Suppress zero strings
    [[ ${DaysMinutesStr:0:1} = "0" ]] &&
        DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/0 weeks, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 0 days, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 0 hours, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 0 minutes, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/, 0 seconds/}"
} # DaysMinutes

# Build array of suspend cycles from Systemd
IFS=$'\n' Arr=( $(journalctl -b-0 | \
                grep -E 'systemd\[1]: Start.*Suspend' | cut -c1-15) )

[[ ${#Arr[@]} -gt 0 ]] && upper=$(( ${#Arr[@]} - 1 ))
[[ $upper -gt 0 ]] && for (( i=0; i<upper; i=i+2 )) ; do
    (( SuspendCount++ ))
    Time=$(( $(date +%s -d "${Arr[i+1]}") - $(date +%s -d "${Arr[i]}") ))
    SuspendTime=$(( SuspendTime + Time ))
    DaysMinutes "$Time"
    printf "%s to %s suspended%s\n" "${Arr[i]}" "${Arr[i+1]}" \
          "$DaysMinutesStr"
done

echo
LinuxTime=$(( $(date +%s -d "Now") - $(date +%s -d "$(uptime -s)") ))
DaysMinutes "$LinuxTime"
printf "Linux uptime %'d seconds (%s)\n" "$LinuxTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
DaysMinutes "$SuspendTime"
printf "%s Suspends %'d seconds (%s)\n" \
        "$SuspendCount" "$SuspendTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
RealTime=$(( LinuxTime - SuspendTime ))
DaysMinutes "$RealTime"
printf "Real uptime %'d seconds (%s)\n" "$RealTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
```

About half the program is converting seconds to human readable format in weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds. The function `DaysMinutes` does this and was copied from my `~/.bashrc` file where you may want to put that function yourself.

---

### How it works

The key component is getting suspend start and end times from `journalctl`:

```bash
$ journalctl -b-0 | grep -E 'systemd\[1]: Start.*Suspend'
Oct 31 05:55:19 alien systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Oct 31 16:54:26 alien systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
 (... SNIP ...)
Nov 07 21:07:28 alien systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 08 05:08:52 alien systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
```

- The `journalctl -b-0` command reads all the system messages for the current boot. You could enhance the function to look at the previous boot using `-b-1` the boot before that with `-b-2`, etc.
- The `grep` command with regex does the heavy lifting returning 32 system messages pertaining to suspend from the 19,330 system messages recorded (on my system)

Comment: It seems to work not anymore in 20.04 ?!? Build array of suspend cycles from Systemd seems not to work. echo $Arr
Mai 03 09:06:53 Mai 03 09:19:28 Mai 03 10:10:09 but next command - what this should be result with '\n' ahead?

Comment: @Arno Can we first confirm what **systemd** returns when you use the example above of: `journalctl -b-0 | grep -E 'systemd\[1]: Start.*Suspend'`? It should show the times going to sleep and waking up.

Comment: Journal has been changed: Better is: "IFS=$'\n' Arr=( $(journalctl -b-0 | grep -E 'PM: suspend' | cut -c1-15) )", but date command gives me "wrong date"...

Comment: date +%s  -d "Mai 03 18:00:00"
date: ungültiges Datum »Mai 03 18:00:00“ (or translated invalid date)

Comment: @Arno I can only test my own code not your code I can't see. I will have to upgrade my test partition to **20.04** and test how systemd has changed in that version. Life is busy with SARS-CoV-2 research and I still haven't installed the 32GB Ram upgrade I bought just before the March 28, 2020 lock down. If I don't reply with an updated answer in 1 week please send me a reminder. Thanks.

Comment: I need to convert the date "Mai 03 18:00:00" to "2020-05-03 18:00:00". Other date formats I can't convert to seconds. I thought I can do that with a format string like +"%b %d %H:%M:%S", but that doesn't work. -- like that -- {date +%s  -d "Mai 03 18:00:00" +"%b %d %H:%M:%S"}

Comment: 2022: around line 42 should be changed to ```IFS=$'\n' Arr=( $(journalctl -b-0 | \
                grep -E 'systemd\[1]: (Starting|Finished).*Suspend' | cut -c1-15) )```

Comment: @Superbiji I'm still in 2016 and just tested the script and it works fine. I plan on installing 22.04.1 and hope to remember to test the script again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After years the above script requires an update. systemd messages and date command are not compatible anymore - as explained in the comments to the upper script. So I take that one as a base and modified it.
Journal returns date as "Mai 03 ..." which can't be handled by date. To work around I faked the year and month - so it will not count properly if month is changed during standby .... Maybe someone will change that.

```
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: suspendtime
# PATH: $HOME/askubuntu/
# DESC: For: https://askubuntu.com/questions/321855/how-to-get-real-uptime
# DATE: November 6, 2019.

# NOTE: Calculate suspend time from systemd's journalctl

# UPDT: 2019-11-07 Fine-tune removing 0 Units in DaysMinutesStr
# UPDT: 2020-05-05 works with Ubuntu 20.04 but has problem with changing monthes

# Duplicate DaysMinutes from ~/.bashrc for Ask Ubuntu
DaysMinutes () {

    local d h m s
    (( d = ${1} / 86400 ))
    (( h = (${1}%86400) / 3600 ))
    (( m = (${1}%3600) / 60 ))
    (( s = ${1}%60 ))
    DaysMinutesStr="$d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds"

    # Convert 1's to singular
    [[ ${DaysMinutesStr:0:2} = "1 " ]] && \
        DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/days/day}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 hours/ 1 hour}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 minutes/ 1 minute}"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 1 seconds/ 1 second}"

    # Suppress zero strings
    [[ ${DaysMinutesStr:0:1} = "0" ]] &&
        DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/0 days, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 0 hours, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/ 0 minutes, / }"
    DaysMinutesStr="${DaysMinutesStr/, 0 seconds/}"
} # DaysMinutes

# Build array of suspend cycles from Systemd
IFS=$'\n' Arr=( $(journalctl -b-0 | grep -E 'PM: suspend' | cut -c5-15) )

[[ ${#Arr[@]} -gt 0 ]] && upper=$(( ${#Arr[@]} - 1 ))
SuspentCount=0
[[ $upper -gt 0 ]] && for (( i=0; i<upper; i=i+2 )) ; do
    (( SuspendCount++ ))
    Time=$(( $(date +%s -d "2020-01-${Arr[i+1]}") - $(date +%s -d "2020-01-${Arr[i]}") ))
    SuspendTime=$(( SuspendTime + Time ))
    printf "%s to %s lasting %'d seconds\n" "${Arr[i]}" "${Arr[i+1]}" "$Time"
done

echo
LinuxTime=$(( $(date +%s -d "Now") - $(date +%s -d "$(uptime -s)") ))
DaysMinutes "$LinuxTime"
printf "Linux uptime \t%'d seconds (%s)\n" "$LinuxTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
if [ $SuspendCount >  0 ]; then 
    DaysMinutes "$SuspendTime"
    printf "%sx Suspend \t%'d seconds (%s)\n" "$SuspendCount" "$SuspendTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
fi
RealTime=$(( LinuxTime - SuspendTime ))
DaysMinutes "$RealTime"
printf "Real uptime \t%'d seconds (%s)\n" "$RealTime" "$DaysMinutesStr"
```

Comment: The problem appears to not be with `systemd` in Ubuntu 20.04 but rather with the `date` command in Ubuntu 20.04. I see you've changed this line: `Time=$(( $(date +%s -d "${Arr[i+1]}") - $(date +%s -d "${Arr[i]}") ))` because the `date` command isn't working.

Comment: True. 3 things I have changed: I go for "PM: suspend" in the journal. Without that change it will only find Starting of suspend, not start and stop. Then I wiped out the month in the log (cut -c4-15) and finally replaced the months by a fixed year and month in different format (Mai 03 -> 2020-05-03) to make the conversion to seconds happen. To improve it it needs some more effort in converting the date.

Comment: May I ask what is this IFS=$'\n' used for ?

Comment: It basically means you read one line at a time. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

Comment: Updated the script - as the previous version show error if no suspend has happened. If someone will take effort to improve month/year transition : welcome. I am atm to lazy to do that.

Comment: Because I haven't rebooted my system in 4 weeks, I changed my answer today to include weeks in the time span.