# how to take the total working hours of the system in a day?

Tags: command-line, login, suspend, shutdown

I need to take the total working hours of the system in a day. That means, take time between power on and shutdown and also subtract the time of system were suspend. Final output must be total working hours in a day. I tried some third party softwares and my own command based operations but all that failed. How can i calculate that. Is there any way? I tried an idea to get the result like this:

- system power on time : "time"
- system suspend at :  "time"
- system wake up at : "time"
- system shut downed at : "time"
- total working hour: ((system shut downed - system power on) - (difference between sleep time and wake up time))

I think it's huge task.
Can u please help me?

Comment: run `last -x` command... something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is only a partial answer, dealing only with the difference between uptime and suspended time.

You could determine the difference between uptime and suspended time utilizing some of the information available via `/proc/timer_list`.

Example 1:

```
$ uptime
 11:58:46 up  3:43,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
$ cat /proc/timer_list | grep "now at"
now at 12734872068331 nsecs
```

So uptime = (3 * 60 + 43) * 60 = 13,3800 seconds.
Active time = 12,735 seconds.
Therefore Suspended time = 13,300 - 12,735 = 645 seconds

Or, just look at the offset time for each CPU to get its suspended time directly:

```
$ cat /proc/timer_list | grep -A 1 "ktime_get_boottime"
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
--
  .get_time:   ktime_get_boottime
  .offset:     668016000993 nsecs
```

Or 668 seconds for each CPU.
Why do the two methods differ by 23 seconds? Because uptime is only listed to the minute. So that answer is really 645 +59 -0 seconds (or, depending if uptime rounds, 645 +- 30 seconds.

So for what you seem to want run this during shutdown:

```
$ cat /proc/timer_list | grep "now at"
now at 25561396304263 nsecs
```

and divide that number by 3.6e12 (i.e. 7.1 hours active time)

Answer (score 0):

All the information needed is in `journalctl`. Not a complete answer but [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186845/307523) is a good start that you can tweak:

```
$ suspendtime
Oct 31 05:55:19 to Oct 31 16:54:26 lasting 39,547 seconds
Oct 31 23:21:21 to Nov 01 04:29:12 lasting 18,471 seconds
Nov 01 05:51:27 to Nov 01 17:08:34 lasting 40,627 seconds
Nov 02 00:01:33 to Nov 02 10:28:46 lasting 37,633 seconds
Nov 02 18:15:59 to Nov 02 19:10:14 lasting 3,255 seconds
Nov 02 21:17:33 to Nov 03 05:31:54 lasting 33,261 seconds
Nov 03 12:06:39 to Nov 03 14:22:50 lasting 8,171 seconds
Nov 03 22:28:12 to Nov 04 04:17:13 lasting 20,941 seconds
Nov 04 05:49:40 to Nov 04 16:48:52 lasting 39,552 seconds
Nov 04 21:45:48 to Nov 05 04:19:26 lasting 23,618 seconds
Nov 05 05:52:05 to Nov 05 16:32:38 lasting 38,433 seconds
Nov 05 21:12:18 to Nov 06 04:16:50 lasting 25,472 seconds
Nov 06 05:50:45 to Nov 06 16:22:54 lasting 37,929 seconds

Linux uptime 574,835 seconds (6 Days 15 Hours 40 Minutes 35 Seconds)
13 Suspends 366,910 seconds (4 Days 5 Hours 55 Minutes 10 Seconds)
Real uptime 207,925 seconds (2 Days 9 Hours 45 Minutes 25 Seconds)
```

The bash script already does the heavy lifting of calculating the amount of time suspended each day from `journalctl`. Modifying the script to get system boot and shutdown times would be a minor enhancement.