# How to generate uptime monthly report in linux?

Tags: command-line, uptime

I wanted to send monthly uptime report to my clients through email. Will any one help me how to generate monthly report.

Comment: I know that otherwise I would not have asked that question . I need some suggestions to generate monthly report.

Comment: I took a 3 days course on jaspersoft and on how to create PDFs from database info. Might be worth investigating if there is something similar near you. That is if the generated info is not good enough. The "tabled" version is also suited to use in Calc or Excel if that is a tool you use more often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick note to the excellent reply made by Rinzwind about **Tuptime**.

The package is available in the offical repository, so you can install with:

`# apt-get install tuptime`

Supossing that you send the report the day 1 of each month, these are the steps:

Get the timestamp of the first day of one month ago from 00:00 hours:

```
$ date -d "-1 month 00:00" +%s
1514761200
```

Get the timestamp of the last day of the previous month from 23:59 hours:

```
$ date -d "this month -1 second 00:00" +%s
1517439599
```

Use this numbers with the tsince and tuntil arguments:

```
$ tuptime --tsince 1514761200 --tuntil 1517439599 
System startups:    25   since   00:00:00 01/01/18   until   23:59:59 31/01/18
System shutdowns:   24 ok   -   1 bad
System uptime:      4.84 %   -   1 day, 12 hours, 0 minutes and 24 seconds
System downtime:    95.16 %   -   29 days, 11 hours, 59 minutes and 36 seconds
System life:        31 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds

Largest uptime:     3 hours, 37 minutes and 41 seconds   from   19:00:15 16/01/18
Shortest uptime:    1 minute and 5 seconds   from   16:40:13 19/01/18
Average uptime:     1 hour, 26 minutes and 25 seconds

Largest downtime:   4 days, 9 hours, 48 minutes and 21 seconds   from   14:11:38 27/01/18
Shortest downtime:  11 seconds   from   16:40:02 19/01/18
Average downtime:   1 day, 4 hours, 19 minutes and 11 seconds

Current uptime:     48 minutes and 19 seconds   since   18:50:03 01/02/18
```

Now you can get this report, or one of the others available like the table or list format, and send it to the clients.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool called "tuptime" that generates information on "uptime" but with a lot more information compared to the single line "uptime" shows.

From their [github page](https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime):

> **Basic Installation and usage**
>
> **Clone the repo**
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime.git
> ```
>
> **Copy the `tuptime` file located under `latest/` directory to
>   `/usr/bin/` and make it executable**
>
> ```
> cp tuptime/src/tuptime /usr/bin/tuptime chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/tuptime
> ```
>
> **Assure that the system pass the prerequisites**
>
> ```
> python 3.X
> ```
>
> **Run first with a privileged user**
>
> ```
> tuptime
> ```

Extra added by me: change the owner and group of `typtime` to your user with:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /usr/bin/tuptime
```

and you can run it without sudo/root access.

From the link one of the keypoints it shows is:

> - It register the times in a sqlite database. Any other software can use it. The specs are in the tuptime-manual.txt. Also, it have the option for output the registers in seconds and epoch (-s) or/and in csv format, easy to pipe it to other commands.

So if you can code you could create your own reports. Or even connect the database to something like [jasperstudio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) and create a template.

Otherwise the command `tuptime` will show this:

```
System startups:    1   since   21:54:09 24/09/15
System shutdowns:   0 ok   -   0 bad
System uptime:      100.0 %   -   21 minutes and 30 seconds
System downtime:    0.0 %   -   0 seconds
System life:        21 minutes and 30 seconds

Largest uptime:     21 minutes and 30 seconds   from   21:54:09 24/09/15
Shortest uptime:    21 minutes and 30 seconds   from   21:54:09 24/09/15
Average uptime:     21 minutes and 30 seconds

Largest downtime:   0 seconds
Shortest downtime:  0 seconds
Average downtime:   0 seconds

Current uptime:     21 minutes and 30 seconds   since   21:54:09 24/09/15
```

or `tuptime --table` will show a tabled output:

```
No.      Startup Date                              Uptime       Shutdown Date   End                   Downtime

1   10:15:27 08/08/15                          42 seconds   10:16:09 08/08/15    OK                 16 seconds
2   10:16:26 08/08/15                          49 seconds   10:17:15 08/08/15    OK                 16 seconds
3   10:17:32 08/08/15            5 minutes and 47 seconds   10:23:19 08/08/15    OK                 16 seconds
4   10:23:36 08/08/15                           9 seconds   10:23:45 08/08/15   BAD                 42 seconds
5   10:24:28 08/08/15   2 hours, 9 minutes and 27 seconds   12:33:55 08/08/15    OK  41 minutes and 44 seconds
    . . .
```

The [tuptime manual](https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime/blob/master/tuptime-manual.txt) mentioned has loads of good information.

You can send the output to a file by adding `>> /home/$USER/Downloads/tuptime.log` to the command. That text file could be sent to clients.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate uptime from particular date to another date?

Comment: @lifetree sure: the data is stored in a database and 1 of the features of a databases is the ability to use dates and manipulate them. Or you could create a script that reads the databases, picks 2 dates and subtract them. If you have specific needs for a report you will need to create that ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @rizwind. I am like new born baby in linux. I dont know where the database is stored I mean which folder, and how to manipulate them. I need little more elaboration.

Comment: Oh you need to start following the generic Linux rule: start reading the manual ;-)  See the link in the question called "tuptime manual". The page it links to at some points states "Define an alternative database file. Default is located in '/var/lib/tuptime/tuptime.db'"  ;-)  and it has lots of command line parameters and options to pull out data. (the database is not likely to be plain text). There is likely also a generic connector you could use if you can code in python :D Have fun ;-)

Comment: You can calculate the uptime from and to another date if you pass the arguments --tsince and --tuntil with the date in epoch format, for example, from 1 Jan 2017 to the end of the year: $ tuptime --tsince 1483225200 --tuntil 1514761199

Comment: How can i generate tuptime table for two dates?

Comment: How to feed the output of tuptime to google sheet?

Comment: Strange your answer was 2 days earlier than accepted answer which is basically the same. However with two extra votes you received more points. OK it's three more votes now then ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention anywhere if `tuptime` takes into account the time system was suspended. If it does not you can use [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186845/307523) to calculate suspend time and subtract it from uptime:

```
$ suspendtime
Oct 31 05:55:19 to Oct 31 16:54:26 lasting 39,547 seconds
Oct 31 23:21:21 to Nov 01 04:29:12 lasting 18,471 seconds
Nov 01 05:51:27 to Nov 01 17:08:34 lasting 40,627 seconds
Nov 02 00:01:33 to Nov 02 10:28:46 lasting 37,633 seconds
Nov 02 18:15:59 to Nov 02 19:10:14 lasting 3,255 seconds
Nov 02 21:17:33 to Nov 03 05:31:54 lasting 33,261 seconds
Nov 03 12:06:39 to Nov 03 14:22:50 lasting 8,171 seconds
Nov 03 22:28:12 to Nov 04 04:17:13 lasting 20,941 seconds
Nov 04 05:49:40 to Nov 04 16:48:52 lasting 39,552 seconds
Nov 04 21:45:48 to Nov 05 04:19:26 lasting 23,618 seconds
Nov 05 05:52:05 to Nov 05 16:32:38 lasting 38,433 seconds
Nov 05 21:12:18 to Nov 06 04:16:50 lasting 25,472 seconds
Nov 06 05:50:45 to Nov 06 16:22:54 lasting 37,929 seconds

Linux uptime 576,297 seconds (6 Days 16 Hours 4 Minutes 57 Seconds)
13 Suspends 366,910 seconds (4 Days 5 Hours 55 Minutes 10 Seconds)
Real uptime 209,387 seconds (2 Days 10 Hours 9 Minutes 47 Seconds)
```

Note the script only looks at `journalctl` for the current boot. You need to turn on  jounralctl multi-boot logging:

- [How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04+ restarts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts)

Also note the linked bash script would need to be modified to calculate previous boots.