# How to see history of suspensions?

Tags: suspend, power-management, history

There are commands to check uptime, history of reboots, but how to check time(s) when system was suspended?
Kubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1186845/925971 does this answer your question?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @Gryu no, there are errors in the script.

Comment: I've tried it and it displayed: `1 Suspends 65 seconds ( 1 minute, 5 seconds)\n Real uptime 25655 seconds ( 7 hours, 7 minutes, 35 seconds)`. It counts suspends starting from the last boot time. It does not count suspends before previous reboots. Just suspended and tried the command again: `2 Suspends 74 seconds ( 1 minute, 14 seconds)`

Comment: @Gryu I'm getting `invalid date` and serveral `syntax errors`, running with `bash <script>`.

Comment: copy/paste it into some `susptime.sh` file, `chmod +x ./susptime.sh` and execute it by `./susptime.sh`

Comment: What's wrong with plain `journalctl -u systemd-suspend`?

Comment: @steeldriver simple and elegant, it does it, thank you.

Comment: @steeldriver: this should be put as an answer